# What is the Nobel prize 2016 about?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, field-theory, topology

What are the achievements of this year's [Nobel prize winners](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2016/press.html) in physics?

What was their contribution and what is/was novel about it?

Disclaimer:
This question is designed to give a thorough understanding of what the topic of this year's Nobel prize is about. The answer should give reference to most cited papers and give an overview of their achievements and an introduction to the topic.

Comment: You can find explanations on these links:

1. https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2016/popular-physicsprize2016.pdf

2. https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2016/advanced-physicsprize2016.pdf

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/251470/13917 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255909/2451