# Kosterlitz-Thouless transition and renormalisation group theory

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, renormalization, phase-transition

I'm trying to understand the [Kosterlitz-Thouless transition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255909/what-is-the-kosterlitz-thouless-transition) in 2d systems. There is a section in Altland and Simons' *Condensed Matter Field Theory* that discusses the phenomenon, but I don't really understand the role of renormalization group theory in the KT transition.

I don't have a background in group theory so the equations are confusing. I would really appreciate a more qualitative description of the main points and motivations.